# IBM Watson Assistant - store slot data in custom defined entitiy?

Tags: ibm-cloud, chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I am using slots in one of my nodes in the dialog of IBM Watson Assistant. The issue is none of system provided entities for slots`(sys-person, sys-percentage, sys-number...)` does not fit my need.

I need a company name to be saved. So I created my own entity named 
`@companyName` added pattern, and when the user enters value it is recognized by the entity pattern but the data is not saved to the entity.

How can I save the answer the user gives to that question in the my entity `@companyName`

screenshots:

### [image: entity definition]

### [image]

[image: conversation with the bot]

### ---

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out!

Everything that I had to do is append `.literal` in the second screenshot after the `Check for: @companyName`.

So now the slots part looks like this, and we have the entered value inside the variable `$companyName`

[image]

I found it in the official documentation, more precisely here:
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant/dialog-slots.html#dialog-slots

(under number 4. **Add a slot for each unit of required information. For each slot, specify these details**)

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to save the entity, but its value...:

You would need to check for `@companyName.value` and save it to the variable `$companyName`. See this [slot using tips in the documentation for IBM Watson Assistant](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant/dialog-slots.html#slots-tips).

This [tutorial showing a database-driven chatbot](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/tutorials/slack-chatbot-database-watson.html) uses patterns to capture data and the code is available. Examine it for some coding examples.

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your effort and answer, I really appreciate it! Unfortunately I can not still solve my issue. I tried replacing `Check for:@companyName` with `check for: @companyName.value` in the 2nd screenshot and the rest left the same but still does not work. Checked the links as well but they are using system enttites there as well... :/

Comment: Sorry, it is `literal`, not `value`. It refers to the actual value that was captured.